# Marketing Cloud - Create Data Extension (Rest API)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Is possible to create a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud using Rest API?
if yes, can provide one example?

Comment: HI Leto, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the tour and read How to Ask. Right now, this post would be improved if you edit it to be more specific and also to contain a question. A good Question post will outline very clearly the behavior you expect and the behavior you observe, and contain a clear question which can be answered succinctly. salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a good overview of the difference between soap and rest: 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no - this is not possible via REST API. Almost all things inside of Email Studio are still only accomplished via the SOAP API.  See below ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm)) for example of SOAP envelope needed to create a DE.

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options></Options>
        <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension">
            <CustomerKey>DataExtensionFromAPI</CustomerKey>
            <Name>DataExtensionFromAPI</Name>
            <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
            <SendableDataExtensionField>
                <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
            </SendableDataExtensionField>
            <SendableSubscriberField>
                <Name>Email Address</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </SendableSubscriberField>
            <Fields>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>ChannelUser</Name>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>ChannelUser_EmailAddress</Name>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>Demographic_Address_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>Demographic_Address</Name>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```